# What does the number mean in WSUS metadata.txt?

Tags: windows, metadata, windows-update

WSUS metadata.txt file line is like this:

```
0c524df0-0404-0050-bf3e-80d80b490d53,00000064,0000052f,<upd:Update...etc
```

The first part is GUID and the last is XML.
What is `00000064` and `0000052f`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where this file comes from but, looking at the numbers, and I think I understand.

Updates in WSUS are identified by three fields:

- Update GUID - Identifies the update
- Update Global Revision Number- Identifies the revision of the updates
- Local Update Revision ID - Identifies the revision locally to the WSUS Server (i.e., it can vary from server to server.)  This field is an undocumented internal field.

I believe the two fields after the GUID, I believe are:

- Update Global Revision Number in Hex
- Local Update Revision ID in Hex

See [Using WSUS Views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb410149(v=vs.85).aspx) for info on Revision Number.